# keeping a value constant from one method to an overloaded method

Tags: java, overloading

I am currently taking an introduction to java course and I'm stumped here..

I created a `rollDice()` method that uses `Math.random` to produce 2 `int` type values stored in variables `d1` and `d2`. If the sum of the values equal 4,6,8,9,10,or 11 a `valuePoint` is established of that sum, and then the overloaded method `play(int d1, int d2)` is called where the dice is rolled again until either the sum equals 7(you lose) or the sum equals the original `valuePoint` established in the first method.

My problem is I cant seem to keep the original `valuePoint` constant because it is first established as `valuePoint = sum`. So every time I roll the dice in the second method the `valuePoint` changes again to equal sum. I hope I explained my problem well.

```
public void play(){
    rollDice();
    sum = d1 + d2;
    if(sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 5) {
        status = "You Lose.";
        valuePoint = 0;
        System.out.println(status);
    }
    else if(sum == 7 || sum == 11) {
        status = "You Win!";
        valuePoint = 0;
        System.out.println(status);
    }
    else {
        status = "You established the value point ";
        valuePoint = sum;
        System.out.println(status + valuePoint);
    }
    if(valuePoint == sum)
        play(d1,d2);
} // end of method


public void play(int d1, int d2){

    final int vp = valuePoint;
    sum = 0;
    start = true;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Roll again..");
        rollDice();
        sum = d1 + d2;
        if (sum == vp) {
            status = "You Win!";
            System.out.println(status);
            start = false;
            break;
        }
        else if (sum == 7) {
            status = "You Lose.";
            System.out.println(status);
            start = false;
            break;
        }
    } // end of while
} // end of method
```

Here is a sample of my output..

```
You rolled 1 + 5 = 6
You established the value point 6  
Roll again..
You rolled 2 + 6 = 8  
You Win!
```

Notice that second roll did not reach the `valuepoint`, but its still a win because the `valuePoint` has been changed to the new sum.

Also the attributes and operations are given in the question so I have to follow this API to achieve full marks. The only variable I added to the attributes was the final `int vp` in an attempt to keep that darn `valuePoint` constant when first established but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually related to scope. In your method `play(int d1, int d2)`, when you refer to `d1` and `d2` in the line `sum = d1 + d2;` you are actually referring to the **parameters** of the function, not the **instance variables** since the parameters have a more "local scope". Thus, you are never actually updating a sum with two new values rolled. You can fix this by either changing the names of the parameters so they aren't the same as the instance variables or by referring to your instance variables as `this.d1` and `this.d2`.